# KeyError:'unique_identifier_msgs' and KeyError:'service_msgs' when compiling interface package

Tags: ros, message, action

I am pretty new to ROS, so please do not expect much from me.

I am building a robotic system for my project, and as of right now I am setting up interfaces to use in the project. I added a message file (.msg) and it worked fine, but when I go to add an action file (.action), it starts giving me a KeyError. After looking at the error message, I thought the package it referenced was not installed (it was showing up first with 'service_msgs'), so I went ahead and added the line `<depend>service_msgs</depend>` to my `packages.xml` file, and I also added `find_packages(service_msgs REQUIRED)` and added that package next to `DEPENDENCIES` in `CMakeLists.txt`. After that, I went to compile it and I got the same error message but with `unique_interfaces_msgs`. I do the same thing with that package, and after compiling I get the previous message: `KeyError: 'services_msgs'`. I try compiling again and I get `KeyError: 'unique_identifier_msgs'`. It seems to switch between both messages, but I cannot tell what the actual problem is. I got the same error message but instead saying `action_msgs` or `builtin_interfaces`. I am very confused now and I do not know what to do. My code right now is below:

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(interfaces)

if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX OR CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang")
  add_compile_options(-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic)
endif()

# find dependencies
find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED)
# uncomment the following section in order to fill in
# further dependencies manually.
find_package(geometry_msgs REQUIRED)
find_package(rosidl_default_generators REQUIRED)
find_package(service_msgs REQUIRED)
find_package(builtin_interfaces REQUIRED)
find_package(unique_identifier_msgs REQUIRED)

rosidl_generate_interfaces(${PROJECT_NAME}
  "msg/Location.msg"
  "actions/SendBotToLoc.action"
  DEPENDENCIES geometry_msgs
)

if(BUILD_TESTING)
  find_package(ament_lint_auto REQUIRED)
  # the following line skips the linter which checks for copyrights
  # comment the line when a copyright and license is added to all source files
  set(ament_cmake_copyright_FOUND TRUE)
  # the following line skips cpplint (only works in a git repo)
  # comment the line when this package is in a git repo and when
  # a copyright and license is added to all source files
  set(ament_cmake_cpplint_FOUND TRUE)
  ament_lint_auto_find_test_dependencies()
endif()

ament_package()
```

package.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-model href="http://download.ros.org/schema/package_format3.xsd" schematypens="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"?>
<package format="3">
  <name>interfaces</name>
  <version>0.0.1</version>
  <description>This package stores all interfaces for use with actions, topics, and services</description>
  <maintainer email="vxw397@student.bham.ac.uk">Vivan Waghela</maintainer>
  <license>Apache-2.0</license>

  <buildtool_depend>ament_cmake</buildtool_depend>

  <test_depend>ament_lint_auto</test_depend>
  <test_depend>ament_lint_common</test_depend>

  <depend>geometry_msgs</depend>
  <buildtool_depend>rosidl_default_generators</buildtool_depend>
  <exec_depend>rosidl_default_runtime</exec_depend>
  <member_of_group>rosidl_interface_packages</member_of_group>
  <depend>service_msgs</depend>
  <depend>unique_identifier_msgs</depend>

  <export>
    <build_type>ament_cmake</build_type>
  </export>
</package>
```

Location.msg (inside msg folder):

```
geometry_msgs/Point location
```

SendBotToLoc.action (inside actions folder)

```
uint8 MAIN_BOT=0

uint8 bot
geometry_msgs/Point final_point
---
uint8 exit_code
---
```

I have also tried adding the 'std_msgs' dependency by adding the line `find_package(std_msgs REQUIRED)`to CMakeLists.txt and `<depend>std_msgs</depend>` in packages.xml, but that did not change the error message at all.

All help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

**Edit:** I realised that I forgot to show the full error, so I am adding that here:

```
Starting >>> interfaces
--- stderr: interfaces                            
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/iron/lib/rosidl_generator_type_description/rosidl_generator_type_description", line 50, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/opt/ros/iron/lib/rosidl_generator_type_description/rosidl_generator_type_description", line 46, in main
    generate_type_hash(args.generator_arguments_file)
  File "/opt/ros/iron/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rosidl_generator_type_description/__init__.py", line 160, in generate_type_hash
    pkg_dir = include_map[pkg]
KeyError: 'builtin_interfaces'
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/interfaces__rosidl_generator_type_description.dir/build.make:77: rosidl_generator_type_description/interfaces/msg/Location.json] Error 1
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:215: CMakeFiles/interfaces__rosidl_generator_type_description.dir/all] Error 2
gmake[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
gmake: *** [Makefile:146: all] Error 2
---
Failed   <<< interfaces [0.34s, exited with code 2]

Summary: 0 packages finished [0.72s]
  1 package failed: interfaces
  1 package had stderr output: interfaces
```

The error message above shows up with other package names in place of 'builtin_interfaces'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Soooo, apparantly the reason for the errors was simply because I had an action in the folder `actions`, and it appears that ROS2 does not like that.  They want actions to be in a folder specifically called `action`. Moving `Location.action` to the folder `action` and changing `CMakeLists.txt` as needed made building pass. I did not even need to add the dependencies `services_msgs`, `builtin_interfaces`, etc.